# unable to listen sound in my Ubuntu system

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

I have installed Ubuntu 12 on my system. I have inbuilt speaker in my LCD monitor. Everything is working fine but I am unable to listen sound when I play music or any video file. I can see video on Youtube but there is no sound.
Have I done any mistake during installation or should I turn on any driver? Please advise...

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
 sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Also you can try

```
 alsamixer
```

and disable auto mute

Comment: What is `alsamixer`?

Comment: volume control application.  https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-alsamixer/

Comment: Thanks @terminal: I will check this today when I login to my Ubuntu system.